# Where is os.environ initialized?

Tags: python, initialization, std

Using this code, many keys are output, but I expected no output:

```
import os

for i in os.environ:
    print  i
```

This is the code from os.py:

```
try:
    environ
except NameError:
    environ = {}
```

**Where does os.environ get its values from?** Where is it initialized?

Comment: This question seems pretty ambiguous. Could you maybe add more info about what you are trying to do and what the issue you are having is?

Comment: Instead of including snippets of the Python source code—which is most likely not broken—you might think about including your traceback.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `os` module starts by importing all names from a platform-specific submodule (such as `_nt` or `_posix`) then does a little normalization.  Clearly the `environ` name (standing for the system environment) **was** defined by the platform-specific submodule (as it's normally expected to be!!!), so the `except` clause in `os.py` didn't trigger and `os.environ` is just the rich dictionary it's normally *supposed* to be.

Answer (score 3):

The quoted code from `os.py` is a backstop. It's saying, if no-one has yet defined an `environ` variable, create one, with an empty dictionary as a value.

But `environ` does exist, because it has been imported by this further up on line 58:

```
from nt import *
```

if you're running Windows, and similar platform-specific imports for other platforms. So in practice `environ` will always exist and the empty dict backstop will never be used.

Why bother provide a backstop then? Well, it's of dubious usefulness in the real world since as far as I can see all the platforms currently supported by the core Python distribution do implement a proper `environ` lookup. However there may be, or have been, unusual platforms where Python runs that do not have environment variables, and it may be of use when developing a new platform not to have a lot of programs fail to run when system interfaces like environment variables are not written yet.